# Apply operation on the next element of the data frame column vector

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply, sapply

Let's say I have a df like this

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                 var2 = c(2, 8, 0, 7, 3, 4, 1, 10, 13))
```

I want to get a vector of values which produce following operation:

```
(x-median(x-1))/median(x-1)
```

where this -1 refers to index of the element in column. For example, for first element in column `var2` the result is:

```
(2-(median(c( 8, 0, 7, 3, 4, 1, 10, 13))) )/(median(c( 8, 0, 7, 3, 4, 1, 10, 13)))
```

> ```
> -0.63636
> ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sapply`, we can loop over index of each value in `var2`, ignore that value and calculate `median` of remaining values and perform the calculation.

```
sapply(seq_along(df1$var2), function(i) {
    med_i <- median(df1$var2[-i])
   (df1$var2[i] - med_i)/med_i
})
#[1] -0.6364  1.2857 -1.0000  1.0000 -0.4545 -0.2000 -0.8182  1.8571  2.7143
```

Comment: Is this faster than a for loop?

Comment: If you write `for` loop correctly, `for` loop can work as fast as `sapply`.